# backbone collection undefined on sync

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

For some reason my collection is set to undefined when I fetch it. If I log the collection before the fetch I actually get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdPH0.png

If I log it after the fetch (when the sync event is triggered) I get undefined.

## The view

```
App.Views.Overview = Backbone.View.extend({
template:tpl.overview,
tagName:"div",
id:"overview",


initialize:function () {
    console.log('Initializing Overview');
    this.collection.on("sync reset",this.render);
},

render:function () {
    console.log(this.collection);
    $(this.el).html(this.template);
    return this;
}
});
```

## The collection

```
App.Collections.Gardens = Backbone.Collection.extend({

model: App.Models.Garden,
url: Settings.API + "/gardens"

});
```

## The Model

```
App.Models.Garden = Backbone.Model.extend({

defaults:{
    id:"undefined",
    owner_id:"undefined",
    name:"undefined",
    width:"undefined",
    height:"undefined"

}

});
```

## The creation

This is how I create the view:

```
var gardens = new App.Collections.Gardens();
    gardens.fetch();
    this.overview = new App.Views.Overview({collection: gardens});
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It's likely that you need to wait for your fetch to return before making the assignment to your overview. Otherwise it is still undefined at the time of assignment. Use a promises library like "Q" to prevent moving on before asynchronous code has returned.

Comment: I fixed it, it was me being stupid and forgot to bind 'this'.

I fixed it by adding
    _.bindAll.apply(_,[this].concat(_.functions(this)));

in the initialize of my view.

Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I would still create the view on fetch's success, or pass the "async:false" to it.